# Pop up window by using shortcut key

Tags: javascript, html, url, shortcut

I wrote a code for a shortcut key. It works, but I want to open a URL in the popup window with Javascript. When I write scripts for popup it doesn't work.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which
      if (keyCode == 17&&81) {
        window.open("urltest.html");
      }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Press ctrl+q to open page.
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I use this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

And:

```
<a href="urltest.html" onclick="return popitup('urltest.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

It doesn't work. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the comments from the javascript entirely? The `<!--` seems to be invalid, since its not closed. It seems to work here without them http://jsfiddle.net/RHyrg/

Comment: Any errors reported in the browser's console? @FireOak - that html-comment-wrapping-JS technique is really, _really_ outdated, but correct as-is.

Comment: The code works for me with or without the `<!-- ... //-->` comments: http://jsfiddle.net/a7tXH/ (tested in Chrome only). But still the comments should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the comments in the JavaScript code and it worked fine for me

```
<script>
    function popitup(url) {
        newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href="popupex.html" onclick="javascript:return popitup('urltest.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Also check if your browser is blocking popups

Comment: It works with the comments too, at least in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/a7tXH/ (Note: you don't need `javascript:` in an event attribute.)

Comment: Yes I reverted back and it does work. Seems like an aggressive popup blocker in his browser

Comment: I removed comments and check popup blocker in Firefox ,but still it doesn't work for me :(